# SharePoint server 2013 - configure appfabric

Tags: installation, sharepoint-2013, appfabric, appfabric-cache

We are trying to install SharePoint Server 2013 on the machine, however before we begin, we need to configure appfabric. It failed due to the error

> unable to configure appfabric cache-the specified service has been marked for deletion

at the time of cache node moment.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this post from Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/search?alpha=AppFabric%201.1%20for%20Windows%20Server) AppFabric mainstream support ended in 2017 and extended support ends in 2022. Can you please provide additional details about your system? Are you able to use alternative caches? If yes please check out the [AppFabric to Memurai migration article](https://www.memurai.com/blog/appfabric-caching-migration-guide)